# PowerShell Script Balloon tip does not show $variable output

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

I have a script that is related to exchange online PowerShell. This script moves mail item from deleted mailbox to a new mailbox and once completed shows the balloon tip with the status. The Balloon tip script has a $variable which does not show the right output.

Script is as below:-

```
$User = "Admin@domain.com"
$mypass = cat "C:\pass.txt" | convertTo-securestring -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$User", $mypass)
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $mycreds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.VisualBasic")
$DeletedUser = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Deleted Mailbox Email Address", "Deleted Mailbox")
$UserMailbox = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Enter Destination Mailbox Email Address", "Destination Mailbox")
$DeletedGUID = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox $DeletedUser | fw guid
$DestinationGUID = Get-Mailbox $UserMailbox | fw guid 
New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceMailbox $DeletedGUID -TargetMailbox $DestinationGUID -AllowLegacyDNMismatch
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$Status = Get-MailboxRestoreRequest | Get-MailboxRestoreRequestStatistics | FW StatusDetail
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = (join-path ([environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')) "EXO.ico")
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = "Error" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Mail Item move has $Status" 
$objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Operation $Status"
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True 
$objNotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(50000)
```

The Balloon tip cannot parse the variable. Can anyone help?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Not clear at all where your error is actually happening, but checking [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.icon(v=vs.100).aspx), `NotifyIcon.Icon` is supposed to be of type `System.Drawing.Icon`, not `String`.

Comment: `FW StatusDetail` -> `Select-Object -ExpandProperty StatusDetail`. And do same for any other `fw Something` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This format works for me, noting that the variable is enclosed in "" with the other text that you have shown above as $objNotifyIcon.BalloonTipText, and not '' as per the rest of the showballoontip() message that I use:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Windows.Forms')
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname('System.Drawing')
$notify = new-object system.windows.forms.notifyicon
$notify.icon = [System.Drawing.SystemIcons]::Information
$notify.visible = $true
$notify.showballoontip(30,'My comments :',"$NumberFiles file(s) are being 
moved",[system.windows.forms.tooltipicon]::None)
```